Output batch file to new log
I have a batch file that I want to output to a new log each time it is run.  I've had a look around and nothing I have tried up to now does this.  It either logs to the same file, over writing the previous log, or the script doesn't run.
This is the core of the batch file:
    dir file*.csv /b
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b file*.csv') do (
    ren "%%a" "%%~naappendedname.csv"
)

It is basically finding anything that begins with file and appends some text to the name.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be most grateful, thanks.

The standard method would be to grab %date% and %time% and by tokenising or substringing, construct a timestamp yyyymmdd,hmmss to append to your filename (yyyy,,, auto-sorts the filenames chronologically) Try using the searchfacility for various methods (like looking fordate/time /*stamp`) and select the method you feel is appropriate.

Also you could probably do that like this instead, @For %%G In ("file*.csv") Do @Echo %%G& Ren "%%G" "%%~nGappendedname%%~xG". As for your problem, you could also probably get away with using "MyScript.cmd" 1>"%RANDOM%.log".

highly recommended read
